# AWS CDK Python adding new ECS/Fargate target group to existing Application Load Balancer (ALB)

Tags: listener, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

So, I want to add a new target group to an existing ALB that runs https

I used a

```
listener = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer,from_application_load_balancer_attributes(
 ......
)
```

when I use

```
listener.add_targets(
)
```

or

```
listener._add_target_groups(

)
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: add_targets() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional
> arguments (and 3 keyword-only arguments) were given

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have looked at the docs to see if you have missed any properties that are required and not missing. A short example would be `listener.add_targets("Target", port=80, targets=[insert-target])`